# NFT contract balance not increasing after minting nft

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I have a contract deployed on `goerli` testnet but I don't understand why the contract balance doesn't increase after minting an nft.

Contract on goerli:
https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x41c13FF48Edc715612763394Ac8D36C4d11b5856

Succesful mint transaction:
https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x4a0248639a427b2a824433dce5712d1d86bf85d8a7658d0215aff8cdc9448ea9

```
    uint256 public constant TOTAL_SUPPLY = 100;
    uint256 public constant MINT_PRICE = 0.02 ether;
    uint256 public constant MAX_PUBLIC_MINT = 10;

    function mintTo(address recipient, uint256 count) public payable {
        uint256 tokenId = currentTokenId.current();
        require(tokenId < TOTAL_SUPPLY, "Max supply reached");
        require(
            count > 0 && count <= MAX_PUBLIC_MINT,
            "Max mint supply reached"
        );

        require(
            msg.value == MINT_PRICE * count,
            "Transaction value did not equal the mint price"
        );

        for (uint256 i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            currentTokenId.increment();
            uint256 newItemId = currentTokenId.current();
            _safeMint(recipient, newItemId);
        }

        bool success = false;
        (success, ) = owner().call{value: msg.value}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send to owner");
    }
```

I tried minting using hardhat:

```
task("mint", "Mints from the NFT contract")
    .addParam("address", "The address to receive a token")
    .setAction(async function (taskArguments, hre) {
        const contract = await getContract("NftGame", hre);
        const transactionResponse = await contract.mintTo(taskArguments.address, 1, {
            gasLimit: 500_000,
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther(String(0.02 * 1))
        });
        console.log(`Transaction Hash: ${transactionResponse.hash}`);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What balance should be incremented? Show us the entire contract.

- If you mean the balance of the NFTs minted to some address, check  the `balanceOf(address)` method.
- But I think by "contract balance doesn't increase after minting an nft" you mean the ether balance of the contract does not increase after calling `mintTo`. The reason behind this can be found in line `(success, ) = owner().call{value: msg.value}("");`. The ether send with a tx when calling `mintTo` is sent to the owner of the contract. For this reason, the ether balance of the contract does not increase, but the ether balance of the contract owner should increase by `msg.value`. Look at the tx you provided, it says "TRANSFER  0.‍02 Ether From 0x41c13ff48edc715612763394ac8d36c4d11b5856 To  0x6c3455607f5592612e9e3754ba37c63123d68722" where `0x41c13ff48edc715612763394ac8d36c4d11b5856` is the address of the contract and `0x6c3455607f5592612e9e3754ba37c63123d68722` is the address of the owner of the contract.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. But who pays the gas fee for the transfer from contract to owner?